# Unmarshal YAML into complex object which may be either struct or string

Tags: go, yaml

Trying to unmarshal YAML into complex object such as `map[string]map[interface{}]string`.
The problem is that I want to be able to differentiate an `interface{}` part between `string` and `Source` which is a struct.

```
type Source struct {
    ID     string `yaml:"id"`
    Name   string `yaml:"name"`
    LogoID string `yaml:"logoId"`
    URL    string `yaml:"url"`
}

type UNFT struct {
    ItemMeta map[string]map[interface{}]string `yaml:"item_meta"`
    // could be
    // ItemMeta map[string]map[string]string `yaml:"item_meta"`
    // or
    // ItemMeta map[string]map[Source]string `yaml:"item_meta"`
}
```

Obviously YAML does not know how to unmarshal into `Source` struct so I have to implement `Unmarshaler` interface:

```
type Unmarshaler interface {
    UnmarshalYAML(value *Node) error
}
```

But I don't quite understand the big picture of unmarshaling process. In general I assume that I have  to manually traverse `*yaml.Node` and call `func UnmarshalYAML(value *Node) error` on every node.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type Source struct {
    ID     string `json:"id"`
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    LogoID string `json:"logoId"`
    URL    string `json:"url"`
}

var data = `
unf:
    item_meta:
      source:
           !struct
           ? id: "data-watch" 
             name: "DataWatch"
             logoid: "data-watch"
             url: "https"
           : "product_any('SS')"
      public_usage:
        "": "source_any('SDF')"
        "provider": "source_any('ANO')"`

type UNFT struct {
    ItemMeta map[string]map[interface{}]string `yaml:"item_meta"`
}

type MetaConverterConfigT struct {
    UNFT UNFT `yaml:"unf"`
}

func main() {
    cfg := MetaConverterConfigT{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &cfg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("%w", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(cfg)
}

func (s *UNFT) UnmarshalYAML(n *yaml.Node) error {
    var cfg map[string]map[interface{}]string
    if err := n.Decode(&cfg); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("%w", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Go [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-b5M5m1JBZk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
type MetaKey struct {
    String string
    Source Source
}

func (k *MetaKey) UnmarshalYAML(n *yaml.Node) error {
    if n.Tag == "!!str" {
        return n.Decode(&k.String)
    }
    if n.Tag == "!!map" {
        return n.Decode(&k.Source)
    }
    return fmt.Errorf("unsupported MetaKey type")
}

// ...

type UNFT struct {
    ItemMeta map[string]map[MetaKey]string `yaml:"item_meta"`
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Nhtab4l-ANT

---

If you need the map type to remain as is, i.e. without adding the custom key type, then you can implement the unmarshaler on UNFT as well and just do a re-mapping with `any`:

```golang
type UNFT struct {
    ItemMeta map[string]map[any]string `yaml:"item_meta"`
}

func (u *UNFT) UnmarshalYAML(n *yaml.Node) error {
    var obj struct {
        ItemMeta map[string]map[MetaKey]string `yaml:"item_meta"`
    }
    if err := n.Decode(&obj); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    u.ItemMeta = make(map[string]map[any]string, len(obj.ItemMeta))
    for k, v := range obj.ItemMeta {
        m := make(map[any]string, len(v))
        for k, v := range v {
            if k.Source != (Source{}) {
                m[k.Source] = v
            } else {
                m[k.String] = v
            }
        }
        u.ItemMeta[k] = m
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/uwboGKf3qnD